# Doctrine - double join with condition

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

I have structure like this:

```
Campaigns
id
visits <- OneToMany relation

Visits
id
actions <- OneToMany relation
orders <- OneToMany relation

Actions
id
visit_id
date

Orders
id
visit_id
date
```

And I need to receive Campaigns with Visits and with Actions and Orders, but only that fullfil condition(their date property is in last 7 days range).

This is my code:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
$qb->join('c.visits', 'v');
$period = isset($params['period']) ? $params['period'] : 7;

$starting_date = new \DateTime("today -{$period} days");
$ending_date = new \DateTime('today 23:59:59');

$qb->innerJoin('v.actions', 'a', 'WITH', 'v.id = a.visit AND a.date >= :starting_date AND a.date <= :ending_date')
            ->setParameter('starting_date', $starting_date)
            ->setParameter('ending_date', $ending_date)
        ;

$qb->innerJoin('v.orders', 'o', 'WITH', 'v.id = o.visit AND o.date >= :starting_date AND o.date <= :ending_date')
            ->setParameter('starting_date', $starting_date)
            ->setParameter('ending_date', $ending_date)
        ;

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I also tried the same way with leftJoin but it returns all actions and orders, not only these in specific date range.

I also tried without condition in join, simple left join with another where, but it doesn't work too.

Do you guys have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: do the joins first and the where condition separately

Comment: Hey, I tried like this - https://pastebin.com/4ECwmp3P, but it didn't work anyways.

Comment: try not to use additional AND in andWhere - please read documentation and start simple - then build up on your experience

Comment: Same result without AND in andWhere - https://pastebin.com/27s6B4MQ, any other ideas other than "read documentation"?

Comment: as I said, start with a simple example (e.g. only one date condition) and build up your full scope in several steps

Comment: Could you add to your question the executed query (get it from your profiler)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. In my database there were records with date starts with 2018 year insteaed of 2019. That was the reason why this query didn't work.